# What to do when professor agrees to send a recommendation letter but does not send it and does not answer emails?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I asked my professor to give me recommendation letter and he agreed to that.
However, he has not sent it for my application yet. He is not even answering my emails since 3 months.(I am sure he is alive!)
I paid the application fee of the destination university and they always send me emails asking about completing my application.

1. what's going on?
2. What should I do ?

Comment: When is the most recent email that you sent him?

Comment: I remember this frustration from when I started in Academia. Many professors receive far too many emails daily, or have so many different things they need to remember that something like this easily slips. Depending on your relationship with your professor, I would just ask them in person as soon as possible - they agreed in first place, so chances are they just need a friendly reminder (and possibly aren't aware of your deadline).

Comment: I am sending email since January, the last one was last week (5 in total)